# My website Cpanel login issue

Tags: cpanel

My Cpanel shows invalid login on every browser only in my laptop but in other computer same username and password work fine.
I cleared my cache and cookies of browser still its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type username password instead of copying paste or something similar. Most of the time we do such type of mistakes.

Comment: it only show login invalid only on my laptop but it work fine on other system that are connected on same IP address. i cleared cache cookies, temp files still show same problem invalid login.

Comment: re-install your browser or try after installing new browser.

Comment: it also not work on firefox , IE do you know something about mac address block because ip address is not block.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps**

**Step1**.open command prompt and ping your domain name,

ping domainname

Also check whether it is pinging properly else contact your hosting provider and check your local isp ip blocked in firewall or not.

**Step2**.I suggest you to reinstall browser and try to access.